# Showing that $\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{x}\, d\lambda(x)$ isn't finite

Tags: measure-theory

> > $\lambda$ Lebesgue-measure on compact unit intervall, $\mu(x):=\frac{1}{x}\lambda(x)$. My question is how I can compute the integral 
> >     $$
> > \mu([0,1])=\int 1_{[0,1]}\, d\mu=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{1}{x}\, d\lambda(x).
> > $$
> >     resp. how to argue that $\mu$ isn't a finite measure.

Especially: Can I make a Riemann-integral out of that and if yes, why?

Don't no the reason why, but IF i can compute that as Riemann-integral it's $\infty$.

Comment: Riemann-integrable functions must be bounded, so no, you cannot use Riemann integration over $[0,1]$.

Comment: This is silly: if the integral were finite, it would follow that $\int n\chi_{[0,1/n]}\rightarrow\int 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mu ([0,1])\geq \mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{n} ,1\right]\right) =\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu \left( \left[\frac{1}{n} ,1\right]\right) =\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{n} }^{1} \frac{1}{x} d\lambda (x) =\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln n =\infty $$

Comment: The problem is: Now I do not understand why $\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^1\frac{1}{x}\, d\lambda(x)=\ln n$. hehe

Comment: You can compute this integral, e.g. with Riemann (it is the integral of a continuous function on a compact interval).
$$\int_{[a,b]}\frac{d\lambda(x)}{x} = \int_{a}^b\frac{dx}{x} = \ln b - \ln a$$

Comment: Ah, because the function $[1/n,1]\to\mathbb{R}, x\longmapsto 1/x$ is Riemann-integrable, it is Lebesgue-integrable and both integrals are the same. Right?

Comment: Yes -- as soon as the Riemann integral is well-defined, they coincide.