# Why the answer in the linked question is treating the integral as Riemann integral and not Lebesgue ones?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

Here is the question:

[An example of $\int_{X \times Y} f d(\mu \times \lambda )$ is finite but such that $\int_{Y} f_{x} d\lambda $ is infinite for some $x \in (0,1).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573238/an-example-of-int-x-times-y-f-d-mu-times-lambda-is-finite-but-such-th)

**My questions are: **
1-If I understand correctly, Why the answer in the linked question is treating the integral as Riemann integral and not Lebesgue ones?

2-Also, how, in Lebesgue integration, we overcomed that at $0$ the $y$ in the denominator makes the integrand undefined?

Comment: Why do you think it was treated as  a Riemann integral?

Comment: The values of  a measurable function on a set of measure $0$ have no effect on the integral.

Comment: so it is treated as Lebesgue integral? but there is no substitution in Lebesgue integrals @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Making a substitution in  a Lebesgue integral is also valid . It is based on the concept of induced measures: $\int f(g) d\mu=\int f d\mu\circ g^{-1}$.

Comment: I did not studied substitution in Lebesgue integrals so I am not allowed to use it @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so how can we write the example in the link mentioned and proof the required without using substitution ? can you provide me with an answer for this please?

Comment: Is there another example that purely use Lebesgue integration? @KaviRamaMurthy